# Bash Case --> function ---> case

Tags: bash

I tried a lot of things, but this design does not want to work in any way

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo "# $BASH_COMMAND";read' DEBUG


test () {  
    case "$2" in
    3) echo "3" 
       ;;
    4) echo "4" 
       ;;
    esac
}

while :
do
case "$1" in 

    1) echo "1" ;;
    2) test;;

esac
done
```

if i use case in case it/s work, and when i use read to $2 it work, but i want to work with keys from command line

Comment: You’re calling `test` (not a good function name, BTW) without any arguments. `$2` within `test` is not set.

Comment: Or to state it explicitly: Outside of a function `$1`, `$2`, ... will be the arguments your script was called with (unless re-set using `set`), but inside of a function those will have the values of the **arguments to that function** and you called `test` without any arguments.

Comment: tnx and sorry for my simpl mistake, now everything works as it should

Comment: This [doc](https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/bash_scripting_guide/c12483.html) might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
test () {  
    case "$1" in

    3) echo "3"
       exit 0 
       ;;
    4) echo "4"
       exit 0 
       ;;
    esac
}

while :
do
case "$1" in 

    1) echo "1" ;;
    2) test $2;;

esac
done
```

Comment: But of course it is a terrible idea to name a function like a standard utility. Even if the OP did it - we shouldn't repeat poor design choices in an answer. I suggest that you change `test` into, i.e., `test4711`.

Comment: i used "test" just for test ))